# Como usar NPOI SXSSFWorkbook para exportar xlsx grande

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Tengo que exportar a cliente en Excel 2007 (xlsx) una tabla de BBDD de 500.000+ registros mediante acceso web.
Usando `NPOI` o `Epplus` todo funciona correcto hasta que la tabla es muy grande y se obtiene un Out of Memory. (ASP.NET-C#-VS2015)

La ultima version de `NPOI` (3.20) apunta que añade Streaming para poder exportar a XLSX.
Estoy usando por tanto `SXSSFWorkbook`, creo el sheet, relleno todos los rows creando las celdas y rellenandolas correctamente...pero al momento de mandar a cliente el fichero, este ocupa poco y solo contiene el Row 0, el header.
No se exportan los registros con el contenido de la tabla.

Si cambio `SXSSFWorkbook` por el tipo no stream (`XSSFWorkbook`), el mismo codigo funciona perfectamente (limitando la tabla a unos 20.000 registros).

¿Realmente `NPOI` soporta streaming?, ¿Alguien lo ha hecho funcionar?

---

Edito: Para realizar la exportacion a cliente he probado varias formas:

```
using (var outStream= new MemoryStream())
{ 
   Response.Clear();                
   workbook.Write(outStream);

   Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "ExportTest.xlsx"));                   

   Response.BinaryWrite(outStream.ToArray()); 
   Response.End();       
}
```

También he probado crear un `FileStream` al que escribir el `workbook` creado para salvarlo directamente en disco...el mismo resultado, en ambos casos solo exporta el row 0.

Todos los rows los genero de la misma forma.

Comment: Podrías poner al de código en donde se realiza la operación de generación del documento o el guardado del mismo para que podamos echarle un vistazo?

Comment: Añadido código de exportación